# XQuery Match assertion on SOAPUI

Tags: xquery, soapui

I have a soap testStep in SOAPUI with an XQuery match.

The XML (simplified) look as follows:

```
<root>
    <element>
        <a>a</a>
        <b>b</b>
        <c>c</c>
        <d>d</d>
    </element>
</root>
```

I want to make an XQuery to get all child nodes from `<element>` removing a child element depending on his node name. My XQuery looks like:

```
for $x in //root/element/element()
return 
if (name($x) != 'a') then $x
else ""
```

I expect the next result:

```
<b>b</b>
<c>c</c>
<d>d</d>
```

I think that my XQuery is correct, I tested with an XQuery online evaluator and looks ok, you can try with the follow [link](http://www.xpathtester.com/xquery/6ee6a8bfa18606ad428f77a6c693d6c7)

However when I use this expression in a XQuery Match assertion in SOAPUI I get the following message: `More than one match in current response`. How can achieve this with SOAPUI?

Thanks,

Comment: How about simply using the XPath expression `//root/element[local-name() != 'a']`?

Comment: @MarcusRickert thanks for the answer, but [local-name() != 'a'] is applying to the parent not to the child nodes, the SOAPUI is returning  <element>
  <a>a</a>
  <b>b</b>
  <c>c</c>
  <d>d</d>
</element> to your XPath. If I change your XPath's suggestion to  //root/element/node()[local-name() != 'a'] in a XPath tester I get the desired result however SOAPUI returns again: "More than one match in current response".

Comment: You're right. I meant to write `//root/element/*[local-name() != 'a']`. Are you only allowed to have one root node in your XPath result?

Comment: Thanks again @MarcusRickert but finally I found a solution :).

Comment: Your answer coincided with my remark. However, I still think that you can simplify your answer using my suggestion.

Comment: I make some attempts with your XPath suggestion in SOAPUI to keep the assertion simpler but I can't find a way to make it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing some tries finally I found the solution, the way to do this XQuery in SOAPUI is specifying a root node in the XQuery expression i.e:

```
<MyResult>
{
for $x in //root/element/element()
return 
if (name($x) != 'a') then $x
else ""
}
</MyResult>
```

Comment: By the way, the XPath `//root/element[name(.) != 'a']` does the same as your query.

Comment: I would recommend using XPath axes instead: `//root/element/*[not(self::a)]`. Typically it's good practice to avoid `name()`, and if you must, use `node-name()`.